# GoogleSignIn - Framework AppAuth not found SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, google-signin, xcode12, appauth

I am following the sign-in instruction from Google https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/google-signin#swift_5

However, I am having issues with Swift code.

I kept getting this issue « Framework AppAuth not found ».

I pod install GoogleSignIn and it installs AppAuth. I am not sure what else to do.

Below is my code

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import GoogleSignIn
struct LoginUIView: View {

@State var status = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "status") as? Bool ?? false

var body: some View {
    
    VStack{
        
        if status{
            
            Home()
        }
        else{
            
            Login()
        }
        
    }.animation(.spring())
    .onAppear {
            
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: NSNotification.Name("statusChange"), object: nil, queue: .main) { (_) in
            
            let status = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "status") as? Bool ?? false
            self.status = status
        }
    }

}
}
struct LoginUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
static var previews: some View {
    ContentView()
}
}

struct Login : View {

@State var user = ""
@State var pass = ""
@State var msg = ""
@State var alert = false

var body : some View{
    
    VStack{
        
        Image("img")
        
        Text("Sign In").fontWeight(.heavy).font(.largeTitle).padding([.top,.bottom], 20)
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                
                Text("Username").font(.headline).fontWeight(.light).foregroundColor(Color.init(.label).opacity(0.75))
                
                HStack{
                    
                    TextField("Enter Your Username", text: $user)
                    
                    if user != ""{
                        
                        Image("check").foregroundColor(Color.init(.label))
                    }
                    
                }

 Divider()
                
            }.padding(.bottom, 15)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                
                Text("Password").font(.headline).fontWeight(.light).foregroundColor(Color.init(.label).opacity(0.75))
                    
                SecureField("Enter Your Password", text: $pass)
                
                Divider()
            }

        }.padding(.horizontal, 6)
        
        Button(action: {
            
            signInWithEmail(email: self.user, password: self.pass) { (verified, status) in
                
                if !verified{
                    
                    self.msg = status
                    self.alert.toggle()
                }
                else{
                    
                    UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
                    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("statusChange"), object: nil)
                }
            }
            
        }) {
            
            Text("Sign In").foregroundColor(.white).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 120).padding()
            
            
        }.background(Color("bg"))
        .clipShape(Capsule())
        .padding(.top, 45)
        
        bottomView()
        
    }.padding()
    .alert(isPresented: $alert) {
            
        Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(self.msg), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")))
    }
}
}
struct bottomView : View{

@State var show = false

var body : some View{
    
    VStack{
        
        Text("(or)").foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.5)).padding(.top,30)
        
        GoogleSignView().frame(width: 150, height: 55)
        
        HStack(spacing: 8){
            
            Text("Don't Have An Account ?").foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
            
            Button(action: {
                
                self.show.toggle()
                
            }) {
                
               Text("Sign Up")
                
            }.foregroundColor(.blue)
            
        }.padding(.top, 25)
        
    }.sheet(isPresented: $show) {
        
        Signup(show: self.$show)
    }
}
}

struct Signup : View {

@State var user = ""
@State var pass = ""
@State var alert = false
@State var msg = ""
@Binding var show : Bool

var body : some View{
    
    VStack{
        
        Image("img")
            
            Text("Sign Up").fontWeight(.heavy).font(.largeTitle).padding([.top,.bottom], 20)
            
            VStack(alignment: .leading){
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    
                    Text("Username").font(.headline).fontWeight(.light).foregroundColor(Color.init(.label).opacity(0.75))
                    
                    HStack{
                        
                        TextField("Enter Your Username", text: $user)
                        
                        if user != ""{
                            
                            Image("check").foregroundColor(Color.init(.label))
                        }
                        
                    }
                    
                    Divider()
                    
                }.padding(.bottom, 15)
                
                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    
                    Text("Password").font(.headline).fontWeight(.light).foregroundColor(Color.init(.label).opacity(0.75))
                        
                    SecureField("Enter Your Password", text: $pass)
                    
                    Divider()
                }

            }.padding(.horizontal, 6)
            
            Button(action: {
                
                signIupWithEmail(email: self.user, password: self.pass) { (verified, status) in
                    
                    if !verified{
                        
                        self.msg = status
                        self.alert.toggle()
                        
                    }
                    else{
                        
                        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "status")
                        
                        self.show.toggle()
                        
                        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("statusChange"), object: nil)
                    }
                }
                
            }) {
                
                Text("Sign Up").foregroundColor(.white).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 120).padding()
                
                
            }.background(Color("bg"))
            .clipShape(Capsule())
            .padding(.top, 45)
        
    }.padding()
    .alert(isPresented: $alert) {
            
        Alert(title: Text("Error"), message: Text(self.msg), dismissButton: .default(Text("Ok")))
    }
}
}

struct Home : View {

var body : some View{
    
    VStack{
        
        Text("Home")
        Button(action: {
            
            
            try! Auth.auth().signOut()
            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signOut()
            UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "status")
            NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name("statusChange"), object: nil)
            
        }) {
            
            Text("Logout")
        }
    }
}
}

struct GoogleSignView : UIViewRepresentable {

func makeUIView(context: UIViewRepresentableContext<GoogleSignView>) -> GIDSignInButton {
    
    let button = GIDSignInButton()
    button.colorScheme = .dark
    GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.last?.rootViewController
    return button
    
}

func updateUIView(_ uiView: GIDSignInButton, context: UIViewRepresentableContext<GoogleSignView>) {
    
    
}
}
func signInWithEmail(email: String,password : String,completion: @escaping (Bool,String)->Void){

Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { (res, err) in
    
    if err != nil{
        
        completion(false,(err?.localizedDescription)!)
        return
    }
    
    completion(true,(res?.user.email)!)
}
}

func signIupWithEmail(email: String,password : String,completion: @escaping (Bool,String)->Void){

Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email, password: password) { (res, err) in

    if err != nil{
        
        completion(false,(err?.localizedDescription)!)
        return
    }
    
    completion(true,(res?.user.email)!)
}
}
```

Comment: Don't make us go to the sources of the tutorials you are referring to.  Either go there and ask them or post the code you have written here.

Comment: Thanks, @ElTomato. I have added my code.

Comment: try 'import FirebaseAuth' instead

Comment: Hi @nicksarno I tried import FirebaseAuth but I am still getting the same error.

Comment: Where in your code is it breaking?

Comment: There are no errors in the code itself. I get this error when I try to create a build.

Comment: @nicksarno I think the easy solution would be to not provide google sign in. 

Looking at the code above how do I only provide to signup with an email address? I tried deleting some codes but I am getting multiple errors.

Comment: I would recommend taking an online course with SwitUI x Firebase and then come back to your app.

Comment: Thanks @nicksarno